# How to get previous value of a Tcl variable in Tcl_TraceVar callback?

Tags: callback, tcl

I have Tcl_TraceVar TCL_TRACE_WRITES callbacks on a few Tcl variables so that I could respond to their changes on the C++ side. In the callback I need both the new and the old values of the variables. The new values are available because the callback is executed after the value has change; how do I retrieve the old value, short of storing it separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the old variable contents separately; at the point where the trace callback runs, the old value has already been replaced. (This is useful enough for code which wants to update itself in response to changes, but less good for when you want to observe the deltas or enforce some kind of veto.) I know this isn't the answer you wanted, but it's what there is.

If you're working with simple variables (or `char *` strings and don't mind them being managed by Tcl's built-in memory manager) and don't need anything special, you could try and see if the [`Tcl_LinkVar()` API function](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/LinkVar.htm) will work for you. It's built on top of traces, and it can enforce a read-only nature (since it has not just a Tcl variable but also a C(++) variable to get the old value from). If you need something more complicated though (like conditional rejection not based on a rule like “can I parse this as a `float`/`int`”) you'll have to code things up yourself.